# updating Solr from Lucene Index

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing, heritrix

I'm currently working on a web archiving project. Basically, what we try to do is archive a collection of websites (using *heritrix crawler*) and provide access to the archived contents through a web interface.

We also offer full-text search throughout the archives. Currently, the index is generated using *nutchwax* (a customised version of apache Nutch, tailored to index `.warc` files, as generated by *heritrix*). Nutchwax dumps out a Lucene index and for using it in Solr, all that has to be done is to generate a correct schema.

This is all done and its running like it should, however the archive is not static and there are new `.warc` files generated periodically.

What I can do now, is to generate a new index, merge it with the existing one and import it back into Solr. However, to do that Solr has to be restarted.
It would be great if the index could be updated "on the fly" as this is usually the case (when updating the index via http requests)

Does anyone have an idea, how this can be done? My first shot at this was generating `.xml` files out of the Lucene index file and posting them to Solr. Is this worth a try or are there more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably leverage the use of multiple cores to accomplish what you need. See the [Solr Wiki - CoreAdmin](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) for more details. I think you could leverage the [MergeIndexes](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin) capability or the ability to [Swap](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CoreAdmin#SWAP) cores for a better experience in your scenario.